# Property 'reter' does not exist on type 'typeof TESTING'

Tags: typescript

What could be the issue getting this error ? I am trying to access protected field from extended class using static method.

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20TEST%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20protected%20reter%3A%20string%20%3D%20'show%20retry'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(name%3A%20string%2C%20public%20age%3A%20number)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.name%20%3D%20name%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20TESTING%20extends%20TEST%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(public%20name%3Astring%2C%20public%20age%3Anumber)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super('sd'%2C%2012)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.name%20%3D%20'indraraj'%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20static%20getReter()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.reter%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20test%20%3D%20new%20TESTING('indra'%2C%2012)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(TESTING.getReter)%0D%0Aconsole.log(test)%0D%0A)

```
class TEST {
    name: string;
    protected reter: string = 'show retry';
    constructor(name: string, public age: number) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

class TESTING extends TEST {
    constructor(public name:string, public age:number) {
        super('sd', 12);
        this.name = 'indraraj'
    }

    static getReter() {
        return this.reter;
    }
}

let test = new TESTING('indra', 12);
console.log(TESTING.getReter)
console.log(test)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `getReter()` is a static method.

It means that it's accessed by the class constructor (`i.e TESTING.getReter()`) and not by the instance, hence - is not aware of `this`, which is the reference to the **instance** of the class and not the class constructor itself.

remove the `static` notation and you'll have access.

For more information follow this post: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#static-properties

Comment: -_- my bad Thank you @Sillicakes

Comment: @silicakes is there a way to access class properties inside a static method?

Comment: You can if you keep a global reference for all instances *outside* and then use the static method to traverse and find the instance you seek.

Comment: Imagine having multiple instances with different values and using a search function to find the one you want. A simple implementation would be to pass each instance to a static key on the class builder after each instantiation.